# Gson does not work correctly with JSONObject

Tags: java, json

My problem is very simple. I have a java object

```
public class Cat {
   String id;
   String name;
   JSONObject ability;
   // getter and setter
}
```

and a piece of code

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
JSONObject ability = new JSONObject();
ability.put("catch", "mouse");
cat.setId("one");
cat.setName("Tom");
cat.setAbility(ability);
System.out.println(new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(cat)));
```

and here is output:

> {"name":"Tom","id":"one","ability":{"map":{"catch":"mouse"}}}

Can anyone tell me why "map" come up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [com.google.gson.JsonObject](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) instead of org.json.JSONObject

Comment: I can not review and accept the edit done by you till I get 2000+ reputations. So compensating here. +1  

Answer (score 2):

`JSONObject` is from `org.json:json` library and `Gson` from `com.google.code.gson:gson`.

You should choose one library and use it. Those libraries doesn't know how to handle classes from each other.

Answering your actual question: `Gson` treat `JSONObject` as any other classes by just serializing their fields.

`JSONObject` have one field

```
private final Map<String, Object> map;
```